# PHP and Ajax: how to find out which object did the user click to pass to php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I tested with some code here, basically the purpose of the html file code is to echo the value from the php file, depending which h3 title the user clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 id="random1" name="random_request1">Click here to get number from php</h3>
<p id="randomnumber">Number here</p>
<h3 id="random2" name="random_request2">Click here to get string from php</h3>
<p id="randomtext">Text here</p>
    <script>
    $('#random1').click(function()
     {
        //On click: ask php to get me a random text file 
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "action.php",
            success: function(newrandom)
            {
                $('#randomnumber').replaceWith(newrandom);
            }
        }); 
     });

$('#random2').click(function()
     {

         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "action.php",
            success: function(newrandom)
            {
                $('#randomtext').replaceWith(newrandom);
            }
        }); 
     });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the action.php code:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['random_request1']) {
    $random = rand();
    echo $random;
}

else if ($_POST['random_request2']){
    echo 'abcd';
}
?>
```

Unsurprisingly, php doesn't recognize the random_request1 and 2 name in $_POST[]. I think I still hasn't grasped the POST function quite well to answer this problem by myself in this case.

Comment: You're not passing those items via your AJAX.

Comment: You can use `$(this)` inside `click` handler

Comment: Right now when you click, you make an AJAX call to `action.php` but you don't provide any additional data. Look at the [API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), it'll show you how to do this.

Comment: @Tushar thanks, I just realized that I could shorten the scrip with $(this) somehow

Comment: @MariM Hmm that looks right. What kind of data do you think that I should send to the php file? Should I assign a value on each of the <h3> tag; and check if the $_POST is equal to that value?

Comment: @vagaryblue Take a look at some of the answers below, like Mohamed's, to get a better idea of how this works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use just one click event

```
$('h3[id^="random"]').on('click',function()
     {
        //On click: ask php to get me a random text file 
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "action.php",
            data: {id : $(this).attr('id')},
            success: function(newrandom)
            {
                $('#randomnumber').replaceWith(newrandom);
            }
        }); 
     });
```

and in your action.php

```
<?php 
  $id = $_POST['id'];
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but can I comment something too? The success callback is not quite what I want to achieve, in this case it seems that the echo'ed values in both cases will replace the content in the <p id="randomnumber"> tag.

Comment: You can check `$(this).attr('id')` in order to determine which selector you want to use. Just modify the inside of the `success` function.

Comment: @vagaryblue you can go through if statement in php .. and echo what you want depending on the id you want .. and in callback use another if statement with a value you echoed from php .. and make the action then

Comment: @vagaryblue updated answer  sorry my bad typo :) $('[id^="random"')  should be $('h3[id^="random"]')

Answer (score 2):

You will want to have a way to differentiate between the senders. Maybe pass a parameter:

```
$('#random2').click(function()
 {

     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "action.php?action=random2",
        success: function(newrandom)
        {
            $('#randomtext').replaceWith(newrandom);
        }
    }); 
 });
```

Or have them go to different endpoints:

```
$('#random1').click(function()
 {
    //On click: ask php to get me a random text file 
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "action.php",
        success: function(newrandom)
        {
            $('#randomnumber').replaceWith(newrandom);
        }
    }); 
 });

$('#random2').click(function()
 {

     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "action2.php",
        success: function(newrandom)
        {
            $('#randomtext').replaceWith(newrandom);
        }
    }); 
 });
```

There are of course more methods. This might not fit what you're eventually trying to do, but it's a simple way to get started.

Comment: I could go the easy way with different php files, but I also want to see how can I achieve the desired result with just one endpoint.

Comment: @vagaryblue That's what the first method in my answer is doing. For your simple scenario, Mohamed-Yousef's answer is probably better. But if you're building, let's say, a search function. It might be cleaner to use parameters in the URL.