# Why does my jQuery Ajax GET-request not receive a response from the server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to let jQuery dynamically add html to my page. Unfortunately, I don't receive a response from my server. My JS code sends a GET request, which contains a parameter (bodypart). The server should return a response including the results from the database, but the response is empty.

What causes this problem?

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function getData() {

    var sPanelHeading = '<div class="col-lg-3"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Symptomen van ' + bodypart + '</h3></div>';
    $( "#abc" ).append(sPanelHeading);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'controller.php',
        data: 'bodypart=Autism',
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(data) {    
        $( "#abc" ).append('<div class="panel-body" style="overflow-y: scroll;"><span class="list-group-item"><b>Vaak voorkomende symptomen</b></span></div><div class="list-group">');

        for (var c in data) {
            $("#abc").append('<span class="list-group-item">');
            $("#abc").append(c);
            $("#abc").append('</span">');
        }  
    }).always(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
require_once( 'config.php' );

$bodypart = $_GET['bodypart'];

$sql = "SELECT c_name FROM condition WHERE c_name = '$bodypart'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$json_response = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $json_response[] = $row;
    }
    print json_encode($json_response);
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st : instead of

```
data: 'bodypart=Autism',
```

use

```
data: {'bodypart':'Autism'},
```

2nd

```
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

Basics of $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'controller.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {'bodypart':'Autism'},
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data){
           alert(data);
        }
    });
```

in php

```
<?php 
    $bodypart = $_GET['bodypart'];
    echo $bodypart;
?>
```

output should alert  Autism  .. if this Ok you can complete your stuff .. if something went wrong .. check your php file path

Comment: I changed this, but still same problem. Could you please take a look at http://tiny.cc/getrequest2 ? You have to click on the head to send a request.

Comment: @Engo what I suppose to see?

Comment: I've added console.log to debug it. Maybe you can use it?

Comment: @Engo  take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169129/php-and-ajax-how-to-find-out-which-object-did-the-user-click-to-pass-to-php/30169248#30169248   ... check your $.ajax and connection with php before doing any stuff else

Comment: I turned out to be a database connection error. Thank you for your help!